# iOS5 -webkit-overflow-scrolling causes touch events to stop working

Tags: ios, ios5, web-applications, mobile, webkit

when using [**-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch**;], the scrolling area does work well,
but it causes touch events stopping work out of the scrolling area.
Is there anyone had the same problem? Who can give me some official links about this new scrolling feature?

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ios5 scroll</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    header {
        background: red;
        width: 300px;
        height:44px;
    }
    .scroll {
        width: 300px;
        height:300px;
        background: yellow;
        overflow: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <button onclick="alert('header');">won't work?</button>
        </header>
        <div class="scroll">
            <button onclick="alert('scroll');">It works</button>
            <div>text</div><div>text</div><div>text</div><div>text</div><div>text</div><div>text</div><div>text</div>
            <div>text</div><div>text</div><div>text</div><div>text</div><div>text</div><div>text</div><div>text</div>
            <div>text</div><div>text</div><div>text</div><div>text</div><div>text</div><div>text</div><div>text</div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

2011-12-27: I have fixed this problem but I still no wonder the real reason.
In my case, I have several sections in one web page, each section has a scroll area and a header, each time only one section is showed and use css3 animation combined with transform to switch sections. when add [-webkit-overflow-scrolling] in the scroll area of all sections, touch events stop working randomly, so I just add [-webkit-overflow-scrolling] in the section which is showed currently and remove it when the section is hidden. That works well but I still don't know what causes this problem.

Comment: Hi, what can't you do? I am running the code on the iOS 5 Simulator and everything seems to be clickable and scrollable.

Comment: I'm sorry about that the code does work well. However, in some complex situation, for example if there were more css rules used, it really causes problems in touch events. By the way, does the css :active effect not work in ios5?

Comment: Did you get it fixed? I am having the same problem

Comment: I'm having the same problem in iOS 5.  My header divs (that open/close long before the scrolling element) has 4 links.  The three left most become unclickable when this class is added to a div further down the page.  The other link is oddly fine.  Updating a device to iOS 6 took care of the issue.  I'm going to try the same fix for iOS 5 by dynamically adding the class only to the visible elements when needed.

Answer (score 8):

I have the same issue, and I can also replicate it every time. I have a page that resizes elements to fit the screen when the orientation of the iPad changes. If at any point the element no longer needs to scroll, it will stop doing so thereafter even if the element is resized back to where it needs to scroll (e.g. flipping back to landscape for me). So it's definitely a bug, but I do have a workaround:

When resizing the element, I'm resetting the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` to `auto`, then setting it back to `touch`. However, you have to introduce a delay between the two (50ms is working fine, didn't try any lower). So what I did was added an attribute of "scrollable" to the elements, and used the code below (using jQuery):

```
$("[scrollable]").css("-webkit-overflow-scrolling", "auto");
window.setTimeout(function () { $("[scrollable]").css("-webkit-overflow-scrolling", "touch") }, 100);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This sounds amazing if it works! Just to verify, you have an `<iframe>` on your page (anywhere), and doing this fixes the scrolling issue when it happens?

Comment: This works, but it causes the content to blink. Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by having an `<iframe>` on the page. Many scripts create `<iframes>` to do their work including social tracking buttons (Facebook, Twitter, G+), analytics tracking (Google, etc.), and libraries like PhoneGap.

It doesn't matter how the `<iframe>` is displayed. `display: none; visibility: hidden; width: 0; height: 0` does not fix it. If an `<iframe>` is on the page it will happen, sometimes intermittently and sometimes always.

The only solution I've found so far (which is turning out to not be very workable in a production app) is to delete all `<iframes>` on the page, create them only when needed (for example, when I need to call a PhoneGap API), and then delete them when finished.

Comment: ThinkingStiff is spot on. We struggled with this for days and found removing the Iframe used for communication with IOS instead of letting it hang around cleared it up immediatly. The problem was difficult to reproduce as it would come and go and effect various parts of the screen.

Comment: This is definitely a real bug and removing the iframe fixed scrolling for us. We are using an iframe for javascript to iOS communication. The fix for us was to remove the iframe 20 milliseconds after we create it and set the src attribute using a setTimeout.  If we removed it instantly then iOS wouldn't get the message.  I actually think the timeout could be less than 20 ms. I tried 0 ms and it worked too.

Comment: This is very problematic when you are having the issue in a much needed iframe.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm I saw the same issue on a web app using extensively touch events and list scrolls.
Before iOS5 I was using iScroll, and everything was working fine;
With iOS5, I used -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch to scroll lists to get faster scrolls.

The consequence is I met random occurrences of touch events no more working on various parts of the app. The issues generally occur after I scrolled a list. it affects randomly elements outside the scrolled area, typically a footer menu.

Reloading the app when in 'frozen touch' state doesn't unfreezes it : to unfreeze it, I had to close the safari tab, open a new one and reload, until I met again the issue while using the app.

The issue is seen on iPad2, iPhone 4, iPhone 3GS, all on iOS 5.0

Eventually, I deactivated the overflow touch scroll and came back to iScroll, and things work well as in iOS4 .

Answer (score 1):

-webkit-overflow-scrolling + CSS3 Animations + Phonegap API calls = touch stops responding.

My phonegap app will work fine until I make a call to a Phonegap API, at which point the touch will stop responding on mainly the first element that has a event attached to it in the current view. A view for my app is body > div.current with the rest of the divs display none.

I can replicate this every time.

It is clearly a bug in iOS5.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation on a few of the answers already listed.

My specific issue was that reorientation caused scrolling to stop working completely when `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` was applied to an element.

Example: Landscape orientation is shorter and needs a scrollbar. Portrait is tall enough that no scrollbar is needed. Reorient to landscape; scrollbar is present but non-functional.

- listen for the orientationchange event
- do something which triggers a layout change on the scrolling element
- ensure that the change is significant enough that the rendering engine doesn't optimize it away. For example, hiding then immediately showing does not seem to do anything. Anything that uses `setTimeout()` seems to work (perhaps it is the different execution context, I don't know).

Fading in and out works, or hiding and then showing with a short delay works (though it flashes). @Sari's solution for changing the scroll properties works and does not cause any visible redraw.

```
$(window).on("orientationchange", function () {
    // use any valid jQuery selector
    var elements = $("[data-touchfix=true]");
    elements.css("-webkit-overflow-scrolling", "auto");
    window.setTimeout(function () { 
            elements.css("-webkit-overflow-scrolling", "touch"); 
        }, 100);
});
```

Note that I haven't tested this fix beyond my iPad 3 other than to ensure that it doesn't cause script errors in Chrome or IE 7/8/9.

Comment: I just tried this on webkit mobile iOS 5.1.1 and it does NOT work. The `touchmove` events still don't fire even when setting the CSS attribute to `auto`

Comment: I didn't design or test this to see if touch events fire. My problem was that the touch scrollbar stopped responding in a specific scenario. If you can create a small sample of what you are trying to accomplish and what isn't working, you should definitely open a new question. People (me included) are having a lot of trouble with `-webkit-overflow-scrolling`

Answer (score 0):

In case this is of any use...Incorporating PhoneGap I was using Zepto to append ajax-loaded, scrollable content into the dom. I was then applying a css transition on it. There were no iFrames on the page.

I was experiencing the same issue as mentioned here, where scrolling would just stop working. When I copied the generated code into a separate file and tried that on the iOS simulator - everything worked as expected.

I eventually got it to work by querying the height of the parent container - just before the css transition. By adding `var whatever = $('#container').height();` the scrolling worked.

Answer (score 0):

To improve a little bit ThinkingStiff's excelent answer, you can avoid blinking
- if overflow:hidden is set 
- if instead of 'auto' value just remove property:

```
$('.scroll').css({'overflow':'hidden','-webkit-overflow-scrolling':''});
window.setTimeout(function () { $('.scroll').css({'overflow':'auto','-webkit-overflow-scrolling':'touch'})},50);
```