# `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` broken for initially offscreen elements in iOS7

Tags: ios, html, web-applications, webkit, ios7

Seeing as GM seed has been released, we can talk about it now!

Looks like in iOS7 "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch" is broken.  touch events for elements that are initially off screen do not fire (or in some cases are just unreliable).

Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
    <head><title>TEST</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <style>

        #scrollbox {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: scroll;
                -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        }

        .touchDiv {
            position: relative;
            width:100%;
            height:80px;
            background-color: #FFBBBB;
        }

        ul, li {
            text-indent: 0px;
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        li {
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
        }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function onBodyLoad() {
            var touchDiv = document.getElementById("bottomDiv");
            touchDiv.ontouchstart = function(e) {
                alert("touched");
            };

            touchDiv = document.getElementById("topDiv");
            touchDiv.ontouchstart = function(e) {
                alert("touched");
            };
        }
    </script>
    </head>


    <body onload="onBodyLoad()">


        <div id='scrollbox'>
                <div id="topDiv" class="touchDiv">Fires an event when touched</div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#' onclick="alert('1')">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' onclick="alert('3')">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' onclick="alert('4')">Link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' onclick="alert('5')">Link 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' onclick="alert('6')">Link 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' onclick="alert('7')">Link 7</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' onclick="alert('8')">Link 8</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' onclick="alert('9')">Link 9</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' onclick="alert('10')">Link 10</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' onclick="alert('11')">Link 11</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' onclick="alert('12')">Link 12</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' onclick="alert('13')">Link 13</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' onclick="alert('14')">Link 14</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' onclick="alert('15')">Link 15</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' onclick="alert('16')">Link 16</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' onclick="alert('17')">Link 17</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' onclick="alert('18')">Link 18</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' onclick="alert('19')">Link 19</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' onclick="alert('20')">Link 20</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' onclick="alert('21')">Link 21</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' ontouchstart="alert('22')">Link 22</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="bottomDiv" class="touchDiv">Fires an event when touched 2</div>

        </div>

</body>
```

I guess this will break the majority of mobile optimised web apps.

Any issues with the above code?  And/or are there any workarounds?

(I have already raised a bug with apple - some time ago, and no response)

Comment: seems there is a history of problems with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763458/ios5-webkit-overflow-scrolling-causes-touch-events-stopping-work?rq=1 - though slightly different issue.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Looks like there is a workaround to this problem on [apple dev forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/885616#885616)

So many thanks to Mr Baicoianu.

Basically you need to listen to touch events on the parent scroll div.  So in my case add:

```
document.getElementById("scrollbox").addEventListener('touchstart', function(event){});
```

to the onBodyLoad function.

I guess this is some event propagation issue, solved by listening at a higher level.

Comment: This caused some interesting behavior on my site when applied.  Certain images would not load (only on iOS devices).  I can't explain it, but I am able to isolate the behavior.

Comment: Glad you found my answer useful!  I submitted a Radar bug report to them a while back – maybe if more devs submit this bug it will gain a higher priority from Apple.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Of course the element I **WANT** as the target is deeply nested within the parent - so the event needs to bubble up through many levels until it gets to the parent scroll div. I wonder what the performance implications of this approach are? Do you have any idea?

Comment: As this is only happening on touchstart, my impression would be the effect would be negligible unless your element is 1000s of parent elements deep - in which case you probably need to redesign anyway!

Comment: The simplest way to test this is in a debug console, in Safari at least when running the debugger against the IOS simulator I had to write it with single quotes, not double so:
`document.getElementById('scrollbox').addEventListener('touchstart', function(event){});`
But it solved my problem: strange behavior (empty touch zones) in IOS7, specially when using absolute positioned divs.

Comment: What a weird hack. I can't see what side effects this could cause. These kinds of workarounds are often the reason why many web apps are broken and behave kinda funky.

Comment: or maybe its because of the fact that the browser itself is buggy!  hence the need for a workaround.  side effects should be minimal...we are just listening to an event and ignoring the response...

Answer (score 7):

The above answer works a treat for me. Here is the jQuery version of the above fix:

```
$('#scrollbox').on('touchstart', function(event){});
```