# iOS 7 Safari can't scroll DIV with overflow: hidden or auto

Tags: ios, css, ipad, ios7, mobile-safari

I'm working on a page with four (4) separate DIV elements that all are scrolled independently of each other.  Using the answer here: [`-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` broken for initially offscreen elements in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736297/webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch-broken-in-ios7#answer-18737266) I was able to get most of the pages working.  There are still a few pages where the DIV holding the main content cannot be scrolled vertically when a side DIV is expanded.

The page structure looks like this:

```
...
<div id="paneTop">...</div>
<div id="paneLeft" class="expanded">...</div>
<div id="paneCenter">
  <div>
    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
      <div id="mainContent" style="overflow: auto;">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="paneRight" class="expanded">...</div>
...
```

Setting the touchstart event listener on #paneCenter worked for most of the pages but those didn't have the extra layer of divs.  I have tried setting the touchstart event listener on #mainContent and all the way up the chain but #mainContent will not scroll when #paneLeft is expanded even though it works when #paneLeft is collapsed and it works whether paneRight is expanded or not.

Note: this issue has only been identified on an iPad running iOS7.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct behavior. If you want it to scroll vertically but hide it horizontally, then target it specifically: overflow-x: hidden (to hide horizontal excess), and don't set anything to overflow-y. This allows for some good control over elements.