# idangerous swiper touch not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

well the code is a lot, but the issue can be summarized like this:

I got two files with html, one of them (main.html) has 2 swipers (indexSwiper, testimoniesSwiper) that works perfectly on mobile and desktop, afterwards I want to duplicate one of those swipers in a next file (events.html) I just bring the code to this file and change the **content (just text inside the swiper but the structure is the exactly same)**.

**However this second swiper on mobile doesn't detect touch event or at least doesn't do anything when i swipe with my finger** and I got a JS file that look for the pathname on the window.

If this pathname is main.html i would do some on.ready If is events.html I would do other things (create the swiper object through a function that I made - which works previously). Some idea what I can be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well all the thing was due to a bug on iOS 7 when we use: `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` that is why all works until I use it on my mobile: the solution is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736297/webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch-broken-in-ios7)